# Connection to MySQL Server

Tags: mysql

How am I able to connect to a database even when mysql server is not running?

Earlier I was getting error 2003 regarding `can't connect to localhost` when i used `mysql -h localhost -u root -p'mypassword'`

I searched and found relevant answers at Stack OverFlow and I ensured that MySQL service was running, but still the problem persisted.

But then I omitted `-h localhost` from this command and used instead: `mysql -u user -p mysql` and entered my password as prompted. Then I was connected to mysql.

In other words I can connect with any database in MySQL server even when it's not running using above commands,But still:

How  does all of this is working?

Comment: Are you successfully connected if instead of `localhost` you specify `-h 127.0.0.1`? MySQL may listen differently to TCP 3306 on the loopback address 127.0.0.1 than it does to local Unix sockets, which may be the default it attempts to connect if given `localhost`.

Comment: If you are using wamp/xampp, sometimes you kill the wamp/xampp and the `mysql` service keeps running.

Comment: No I am not using wamp/xamp

Comment: I executed above commands on Command Prompt.

Comment: Reply to Vian: Even if I specified '-h 127.0.0.1'  I was unable to coonect.

Comment: What os? You say it it not running. How do u know that?

Comment: OS:Windows.   go to: Control Panel>Administrator>Services>MySQL>Properties   :That's how I knew that server is not running.

Answer (score 0):

Type in

```
netstat -tlnp
```

If you see

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3306                0.0.0.0:*                   LISTEN      1711/mysqld
```

that means mysql is listening on all interfaces and then loopback should work also, like in my case (i used -h localhost).

I'm supposing you have disabled logon on loopback and have like 192.168.1.100:3306 for example.

Regards,
Mirko

Comment: Are you sure the command is complete,i mean no semicolon etc.,as returning above command on MySQL prompt is further prompting for input.Further,returning above command on C:\> gives following details:NETSTAT [-a] [-b] [-e] [-f] [-n] [-o] [-p proto] [-r] [-s] [-x] [-t] [interval]

Comment: aaah this is for unix, i didn't know you are on Windows env

Comment: try as `netstat -a -b -n` in cmd